# (333c7ef) Stream closed with status: Status{code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, description=Quota exceeded., cause=null}

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I am trying to sign in, it shows me this error.

I checked for quota exceeded errors online but wasn't able to relate the reason to my case, because I am the only one operating this app currently and therefore the the number of authentication requests hasn't even passed 20. I checked that the text form field is registering the entered data. Also, the user is created on Firebase authentication but not on Firestore database. I have changed the rules on firestore so that we can write on it.

Here is the code for my sign in page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:live_location_app/screens/Home.dart';

import 'login_screen.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {

  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String name= '';
  String location= '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Row(
          children: [SizedBox(width: 80,),
            Text('Sign Up',style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(fontSize: 30.0)),

          ],
        )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[900],
        toolbarHeight: 70.0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[200],
      body:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [

               Image.network('https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1120654-200.png'),

            Container(
              width:370,
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  email = val;
                  print(email);
                },
                cursorColor: Colors.brown,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Email ID",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[800],fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20.0),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 10, 0),

                  fillColor: Colors.brown,
                  focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.brown, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Container(
              width:370,
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  password = val;
                  print(password);
                },
                obscureText: true,
                cursorColor: Colors.brown,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Password",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[800],fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20.0),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 10, 0),

                  fillColor: Colors.brown,
                  focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.brown, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Container(
              width:370,
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  name = val;
                  print(name);
                },
                cursorColor: Colors.brown,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Name",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[800],fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20.0),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 10, 0),

                  fillColor: Colors.brown,
                  focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.brown, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40.0),
            Container(
              height: 70.0,
              width: 200,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                  try {
                    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    );
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
                      .doc(email)
                      .set({
                        'name' : name,
                        'email': email,
                        'uid' : email,
                        'Location': location,
                      'password': password,
                      })

                      .then((value) {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home( name: name, email: email)));
                      })
                      .catchError((err) {
                        print(err);
                      });

                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                      print('The password provided is too weak.');
                    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                      print('The account already exists for that email.');
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                  primary: Colors.brown[900],
                  elevation: 10.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Sign Up',
                  style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Divider(thickness: 2.0),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Center(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: 110.0),
                  Text("Already have an account?",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
                  GestureDetector(onTap: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen( )));

                  },
                      child: Text('Login',
                          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontSize: 15.0)))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to say what caused the breach of the quota limits with the information you shared, but the fact here is that the error you are getting is indeed the quotas exausted error, so in order to fix it you are going to need to increase your quota.

Assuming you are a free tier user, based on what you mentioned in your question, I recommend you to take a look at [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) to see more information on pricing and consider moving to the Blaze plan (which has a pay as you go basis).

Comment: Thanks, actually the problem got resolved by cold booting my android emulator. Ig it removed cache and extra memory maybe.

Comment: @Mansi Good to know, in that case, consider posting this solution in an answer so others can refer to it if they face the same issue.